# Problema con un while en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando hacer un while dentro de un ciclo each para obtener un dato que seria el total de la cabaña arrendada, que puede ser una o dos o mas cabaña, este es parte del código

```
<% @rooms.each do |rm|%>
  <% cont = 1 %>
  <% while @cont == @rooms.count do %>
    <% @ttls.each do |tt|%>
      <%= tt %>
    <% end %>
    <% @cont = @cont + 1 %>
  <%end%
  <div clase= "row">
    <div class= "col-sm-12">
      <h4><%= rm.name %></h4>
      <small"> Precio:$ <%= rm.price %> </small>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Metros : <%= rm.meter %>
        </li>
     </div>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

lo que quiero lograr es por ejemplo alguien alquila una cabaña por 3 dias a un valor de 30 dolares eso seria un total de 90 ademas de esa cabaña puedes arrendar la que desees.

Pero no sale nada del valor en el ejemplo que le envío esta con habitaciones, y debe estar debajo del nombre de la habitación o cabaña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ojo la variable de instancia @ttls son los datos y es un array de n elementos, en este caso 2

Me pueden ayudar y explicarme que estoy haciendo mal

Gracias

Comment: Te falta el `@` en `<% cont = 1 %>`, por eso no entra al `while`.

Comment: Yo lo hice pero sabes que solo resulta cuando hay una sola habitación y con mas no muestra

Comment: Me funciona solo con un solo registro cuando es mas no lo muestra